# How can I retrieve the list of selected IDs on index page using Javascript in ActiveAdmin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, activeadmin

I'm using ActiveAdmin. I'd like to be able to get a list of the IDs for everything that is selected on an index page in Javascript. Is there an easy way to do this?

The built in ActiveAdmin batch actions submit via an ajax request, so I would hope there might be some undocumented ActiveAdmin javascript hooks I can take advantage of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveAdmin doesn't provide any JavaScript hooks into the batch actions because it implemented with a standard HTML form.

With jQuery a CSS selector can be used to find checked `input` elements with the name `collection_selection[]` and then map their form values to an array. Each value will be the string version of the record ID (see example below).

```
var items        = $("input[name='collection_selection[]']");
var checkedItems = items.filter(":checked");
var ids          = $.map(checkedItems, function (item) { return $(item).val(); });

// Example output
// ids = [ "14", "25", "26" ]
```